# Is there anyway to load pdf from local file directory without activeX in internet explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

In my workplace. All staff need to open a file to check a calendar and a schedule by clicking the link that open a file in shared local drive. But if someone kept open it, we can't update the file since the file is being open somewhere. Is there anyway to prevent this or is there any code that I can use to download .pdf document and show it in the website without keep opening the local target file?

I already tried to redirect the page back to homepage every three minutes but It needs activeX and due to security concern. The I.E. blocked activex from being used. so I can't use activex needed code.

I need a solution that will work and will not show activeX block message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer code example below will help you to download the file in Internet Explorer. In other browsers it will embed the PDF file and display on the page.

You can call an HTML in page **iframe** which contains **object** tag.

Demo.Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="pdf">
          <iframe src="pdf.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
               <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
          </iframe>
   </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Pdf.Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <object data="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        <p>It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. <a href="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a>. 
       <embed src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Further, you can modify the code based on your requirement.